# possible to use relative path using css in webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

in xpath, we could use "./" as relative path, is it doable in css? I need to loop a row in the table, and then for each cell need to do something, so I need related path, in xpath it's easy by using ".//td" where . is the current row element in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in CSS entirely, but when using Selenium, if you have a reference to an element already, the CSS selector will be magically scoped everything **underneath** that element.

By this, I mean:

```
WebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("something));
elements = element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div"));
```

`elements` would now contain a list of all `div`'s children to `element`. The same can be said for all other selectors (I believe) **except** XPath.

Answer (score 0):

if your HTML looks like sonething like this it is possible

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

your selector should look like

```
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(3)
```

And, if you need to perform any action in sequential order just increase your loop inside the nth-child()

Answer (score 0):

There is `no relative path in css selector` as we have in XPATH. But there are different ways to achieve it through css selector. You can look at [See here](http://seleniumtestautomationtipsandtricks.blogspot.in/2013/01/finding-elements-using-class-selector.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean relative path to a web element you can do something like this:

```html
element =driver.find_element_by_id("pagination") 
element=element.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='confirm-nav next']")
```